# show graphical interface of a jpanel in a jframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphic

What I did is: I created a subclass of `java.swing.JPanel`

```
public class TableInterfaceBDD extends javax.swing.JPanel
```

I then created all of my textfield areas, my Jtable, etc. in that class.

Then I created a subclass of `java.swing.JFrame`, which will be my main class

```
public class MainTableInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

and I wrote this code in `MainTableInterface`:

```
public MainTableInterface() {
    initComponents();
    TableInterfaceBDD pan = new TableInterfaceBDD();
    this.setContentPane(pan);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.validate();
}
```

But my graphical interface that I worked on TableInterfaceBDD doesn't show up. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Why are you subclassing JFrame? I'd recommend you just create a regular one and call all of the commands you have listed in the constructor on that... Also, calling this.setVisible(true) in the frame's constructor rings alarm bells with me

Comment: Besides @ControlAltDel good advice, there's a missing call to [pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) method. You shouldn't set the content pane directly either, but add your panel to it instead.

Comment: My project is about creating a component in netbeans. So in order to make that happen i must work with a class that is an extend of a Jpanel.

Comment: @dic19 how can i make that happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My very first suggestion is to start with [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) tutorial.

That being said, since your `TableInterfaceBDD` class is a `JPanel`, you can add it to another components, for instance a frame's content pane:

```
public class MyGui() {

    public void createAndShowGui() {

        JPanel yourCustomPanel = new TableInterfaceBDD();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);        
        frame.add(yourCustomPanel );
        frame.pack(); // don't forget to pack() the frame
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then in a *main* method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MyGui().createAndShowGui();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new YourFrame(title, new YourPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    };
  }
}

public class YourFrame extends JFrame {
  public YourFrame(String title, JPanel panel) {
    super(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
}

public class YourPanel extends JPanel {
  // your panel
}
```